# Philadelphia Code for Distance of Switch from sink for garbage disposal?

Tags: electrical

How far from the garbage disposal should the switch be to meet code?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We don't generally know location-specific code details, but let's see if someone answers. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Hi Karen, seems like you submitted a partial question.  You can [click here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/169730/edit) or the questions edit link to finish the incomplete question you started.

Answer (score 2):

You can have the switch adjacent to the sink. As far as code the national electric code has no specific limitations on the switch location, it has a specific length for the power cord of 18”-36” per NEC 422.16. But there is not a defined location for the switch. You probably would want it within 2’ similar to the current requirement for outlet spacing.